# How do I get to the base URL for the CardDAV protocol?

Tags: webdav, carddav

I want to get the vCards that exist for an account. The server is `google.com` and I know the username/password. What I dont know is what the correct base url is. Doing a PROPFIND on google.com yields service not available. I had a similar problem with the icloud CardDAV (which I hacked by hardcoding the full address) which leads me to believe that there must be a proper way to discover the base url. Searching the RFC's i could not find it though. Furthermore, CardDAV apps seem to be able to find the data without any problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: do you have any luck with it? i have came across with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://google.com/.well-known/carddav as a starting point. This should work for iCloud as well.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use this [github projet](https://github.com/Metric/CardDavNet) (for .NET). The README tells us to use this url (with a proper username) :
https://google.com/m8/carddav/principals/__uids__/username@gmail.com/lists/

But I didn't achive to see my contacts or create new ones with this code, google just respond HTML 200 OK or 400 Bad Request.

This [article](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/12/15/sync-google-contacts-with-thunderbird-using-carddav/) indicate : https://google.com/m8/carddav/principals/__uids__/username@gmail.com/lists/default/

You can find the results of our research [here](https://github.com/Metric/CardDavNet/issues/1). But some [sources](http://www.bynari.net/can-i-access-my-calendars-and-contacts-with-other-clients-via-caldav-and-carddav/) says that the CardDAV URL of google is no longer available.